# How to disable InteliJ default code format splitting method calls?

Tags: java, code-formatting, intellij-14

[image]

When trying to use the default code format definitions of Intelij (2016.2)
and marking true for the checkbox "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" the attached mehtod calls, getSizeX() in this example is being split into getSizeX in one line and ()); in the other line, how can i disable this behavior ? 
the "right margin" was defined to be 85 and the expected behavior is:[image]